# Defining plot windows in advance

Tags: r, plot, window

I'm a newbie in R. I just finished an elementary course on R and didn't have much training in graphic issues.
Is there a command to define as many graphical windows as needed in advance?

I found plots are overwritten when using console (not in RStudio) when a new plot is issued, unless I add `dev.new()` as a command before each plot command (whatever the type: `matplot`, `hist`, `boxplot`, `qqnorm`, etc).

Notice I don't like multiple graphs in a single device, like those obtained with `par(mfrow)` or `split.screen`. I just want new devices to be setup at the beginning of my script to overcome the need to repeat `dev.new()` each time a plot will be issued.

Comment: You can't pre-set up multiple devices. Save your plots as you go (using e.g. `png()` or `pdf()`). You might also find it easier working from a script rather than in the console - much easier to rerun lines of text. But RStudio is worth the minimal effort to get used to too.

Comment: Thanks for your comment geryan. In fact, I use both RStudio and rite to write scripts and run them immediately to test them. Besides, I intend to divert the graphs to different screen windows, not to printable files like png or pdf, at the momento. Thanks you again. Regards.